# How to implement AAD B2C and OKTA Integration?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, okta

We have a requirement to integrate ADB2C with OKTA as an external Identity Provider.

OKTA will hold the External users and these users needs to access the applications hosted on Azure.

How do I implement the Integration between AAD B2C and OKTA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting your query. In order to integrate OKTA as IDP, kindly follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-saml?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy. It has to be added as a SAML IDP

You can configure Azure AD B2C to allow users to sign in to your application with credentials from external social or enterprise SAML identity providers (IdP). When Azure AD B2C federates with a SAML identity provider, it acts as a service provider initiating a SAML request to the SAML identity provider, and waiting for a SAML response. In the following diagram:

[image: SAML IDP B2C FLOW]

- The application initiates an authorization request to Azure AD B2C.
  The application can be an OAuth 2.0 or OpenId Connect application, or
  a SAML service provider.
- In the Azure AD B2C sign-in page, the user chooses to sign-in with a SAML identity provider account (for example, Contoso). Azure AD B2C
  initiates a SAML authorization request and takes the user to the SAML
  identity provider to complete the sign-in.
- The SAML identity provider returns a SAML response. Azure AD B2C validates the SAML token, extracts claims, issues its own token, and
  takes the user back to the application.

Yes, Azure Active Directory B2C has a free tier for your first 50,000 active users per month (MAU), which you can use for testing purposes. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/trial/get-started-active-directory-b2c/

- Log in to the Azure portal by using your existing Azure subscription or by starting a free trial. On the left side, click on the New button and search for B2C. Click Create.
- Click Create a new Azure AD B2C tenant and fill in all the fields.
  Once you are ready click Create and wait for creation of your
  directory to finish.
- Once your directory is created, a prompt will appear notifying you
  your new directory is ready. Click on the link in the prompt to
  access your new directory.
- The B2C settings blade appears, where you configure and manage your
  Azure Active Directory B2C directory.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, Is it possible to setup the Azure B2C AD with the trail account? If so, please help me with the steps.

Comment: I have updated the above answer with steps to configure Azure B2C. Please do review it and let me know.